# html a tag send an object with href

Tags: javascript, html, express

I have the following `<a>` tag that links to another URL:

```
<a class="button1 mainButton title" href='/link1'>Sign up</a>
```

In my Express backend, I am delivering the corresponding HTML file:

```
router.get("/link1", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../link1.html"));
});
```

There is an additional functionality that I would like to achieve. I have two types of users, and the identity of the user can only be determined at the frontend. Users who have `identity1` should see `link1.html`, and users with `identity2` should see `link2.html`. I am wondering if there is a possibility to send a JSON object along with the href request. For example, something like `<a class="button1 mainButton title" href='/link1' hrefObj = {identity: "identity1"}>Sign up</a>` (just made the previous line up). With the sent object, I can send the appropriate HTML file from the backend based on the identity received. I did some research and was not able to find a solution that I was looking for.

Comment: Weird that only the front end has state.....

Comment: If the pages contains sensitive info, that's not secure. Don't do that.

Comment: Hi, you can not send object from link but you can pass query parameters with the URL and can retrive it's value in Express backend.
<a class="button1 mainButton title" href='/link1?identity=identity1'>Sign up</a>
You can follow this tutorials. https://stackabuse.com/get-query-strings-and-parameters-in-express-js/
I hope this will be helpful. Thanks